# canvas fill text changed when hovering over chartjs tooltips

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

Chart after initial load.

[image]

Hovering over chart.js tooltips.

[image]

Here is the code I am using to add the text on the canvas.

```
plugins: [{
  afterDraw: function (chart) {
    let text = '0.9712'
    let textX = 464
    let textY = 85
    chart.ctx.fillStyle = '#36a2eb'
    chart.ctx.fillRect(textX - 10, textY - 13, 100, 17)
    chart.ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff'
    chart.ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY)
  }
}]
```

What causes this?